# How to add javascript output to initial state in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Want to initialize date as

```
constructor(){ 
    this.state={
    date:{new Date().getDate()+"-"+new Date().getMonth()+"-"+new Date().getFullYear()}
}
}
```

but not working. How we can add js to state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need remove the curly brackets to achieve this

```
date:new Date().getDate()+"-"+new Date().getMonth()+"-"+new Date().getFullYear()
```

Right now , you're adding the `object` without a `key` to the `state object`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to set date to current date it is not happening because you are putting it inside curly braces so it expecting an object.
just remove the curly braces.